# Storyboard objects with custom classes that inherit standard UI classes do not update to model's values when view reappears

Tags: xcode, swift, uiviewcontroller, iboutlet

I have a game view that a user could leave to change game settings in a different view and then return to the game view with the game settings updated but the game, otherwise, undisturbed. This seems like a no-brainer but everything from my model is loading in the view as it should with the exception of any UI object that is a custom class.

For example;
`aPlayer` could inherit `UIButton`...

```
class aPlayer: UIButton {
    var name = "Player 1"
    var score = 0
}
```

If I declare the `UIButton` in the storyboard as `aPlayer` instead of leaving it at it's default `UIButton` then my custom class UI objects work as expected *until* I navigate to the settings view and back again. At which point, any objects identified as custom classes visually appear to the end user the way those objects were set up in the storyboard.

Basically, when navigating back to the game view, custom class UI objects are oblivious to any code telling them to update, appear, or function as they did prior to leaving the game view initially.

I don't think the solution is rebuilding my app without using any custom UI classes because then I would loose the functionality that my custom class was designed for.

What do I need to do to have my custom classes respond like non-custom classes when the views change?

**EDIT**
Updated for clarity.

Comment: Can you explain the second paragraph (right after the code fragment)? From the user's perspective, there should be no difference between an "aPlayer" and a "UIButton." Do you mean the object's class changes back to a UIButton?

Comment: @ConnorNeville, Thanks for the quick reply. If I declare the UIButton in the storyboard as `aPlayer` instead of leaving it at it's default `UIButton` then it works as expected _until_ I navigate to the settings view and back again. At which point, any objects identified as custom classes visually appear to the end user the way those objects were set up in the storyboard. Basically oblivious to any code telling them to update, appear, or function as they did prior to leaving the game view initially. Does this add clarity or confuse things?